# Request failing over https nginx reverse proxy in front of http haproxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, haproxy

I want to deploy **webapp** and it's **rest api** over https;

```
end user => https nginx => http haproxy => http app specific
```

- Service app:  (haproxy) http://app.service.consul , (nginx) https://app.domain.com (NodeJS webapp)
- Service api: (haproxy) http://api.service.consul, (nginx) https://api.domain.com (Springboot rest api)

my request from app to api produce the following

[image]

1. Why do I see the Remote address used in the intranet ?
2. What is the appropriate configuration procedure for handling ssl over these two apps correctly ?

Comment: `401 Unauthorized` is not technically a "failure," it means your credentials are invalid or absent (there's no `Authorization` header in the request, though this api may not expect one. *Why do I see the Remote address used in the intranet?*  Because that's how you have it configured(?)  How would we know?  It's neither clear what you're actually asking nor whether this is or is not "working" or to what extent, based on the info provided. It seems to be working at some level, but you need to look at your logs and see why nginx or something behind it is returning the 401.

Comment: The `Authorization` header comes after this login `request`. The login and password used for the login works fine. How do you configure the `Remote address ` ?